# Считать составной тип в структуру

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, golang

Есть тип:

```
   CREATE TYPE ComprositiontTransfer AS (
        Id BIGINT,
        Name CHARACTER VARYING,
        COUNT BIGINT,
        Price NUMERIC,
        IdExport CHARACTER VARYING,  
        IdImport CHARACTER VARYING
    );
```

В таблице:

```
CREATE TABLE "Transfer" (
    "Id" serial NOT NULL,
    "Date" TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME zone NOT NULL,
    "OrgPostav" CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
    "NameSklad" CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
    "Сomposition" ComprositiontTransfer[] NOT NULL,
    "Operator" CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
    "Total" NUMERIC,
    "Changed" BOOLEAN,
    "OneCid" CHARACTER VARYING,
    CONSTRAINT Transfer_pk PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
) WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Теперь перейдем к go:

```
type Rez struct {
    Id          int64
    Date        time.Time
    OrgPostav   string
    NameSklad   string
    Сomposition СompositionS
    Operator    string
    Total       float64
}

type СompositionS struct {
    Id    int64
    Name  string
    Count int64
    Price float64
}

Сам запрос: `"SELECT \"Id\", \"Date\", \"OrgPostav\", \"NameSklad\", \"Сomposition\", \"Operator\", \"Total\" FROM \"Prixod\" LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2"`

Rows, err := Requests.Query("qPrixodSelectByAll", 10, 0) /*этот запрос получает весь список*/
    if err != nil {
        println(err)
    }

    for Rows.Next() {
        var ss Rez
        Rows.Scan(&ss.Id,
            &ss.Date,
            &ss.OrgPostav,
            &ss.NameSklad,
            &ss.Сomposition,
            &ss.Operator,
            &ss.Total)

        fmt.Println(ss.Сomposition)
    }
```

Дак вот в структуре ss.Сomposition пустота. Как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в коде сразу несколько замечаний и ошибок. Во-первых, инициализмы не соответствуют [рекомендациям](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#initialisms), `Id` должно быть `ID`.

Во-вторых, у вас в коде смешаны русские и английские буквы, например в `Сomposition` заглавная `С` - русская.

В-третьих, вы пытаетесь загрузить то, что определено в SQL-коде как массив структур в одну структуру.

В-четвёртых, драйвера не умеют мапить структуры постгреса напрямую в гошные структуры, для этого надо удовлетворить интерфейс [`database/sql.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner). Вот пример для одного `Composition`:

```
func (c *Composition) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    log.Println(string(src.([]byte)))
    s := string(src.([]byte))
    // Убираем скобки.
    s = s[1 : len(s)-1]

    // Разделяем.
    parts := strings.Split(s, ",")

    // Парсим части.
    var err error
    c.ID, err = strconv.Atoi(parts[0])
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    c.Name = parts[1]
    c.Count, err = strconv.Atoi(parts[2])
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    c.Price, err = strconv.ParseFloat(parts[3], 64)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Если вы всё же хотите загрузить сразу массив, то вам будет легче в запросе взять `to_json("Composition")`, а в го определить тип `Compositions`, который умеет считывать себя из БД через JSON:

```
type Compositions []Composition

func (c *Compositions) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    b := src.([]byte)
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, c)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, могу вас уверить, что там C не русская =) Видимо здесь как то проскочило =)